# prevent duplicate fields in multiple rows of a table in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below tables in my SQL Server database:

**Teacher**

```
tid INTEGER
did INTEGER
fname VARCHAR
lname VARCHAR
email TEXT
```

**Course**

```
cid INTEGER
cname VARCHAR
units INTEGER
```

**Teach**

```
cid INTEGER
tid INTEGER
semester
exam time
exam class
```

Now I want to prevent insertion of rows for table "Teach" that have same values for "exam time" and "exam class". Notice that "Teach" could have rows with same "exam time" and different "exam class" and also rows with same "exam class" and different "exam time".

How do I perform this restriction on my table?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code. If you have some test data to try out, post it also. Use SQLFiddle, is a useful tool for this purpose.

Comment: Try Composite unique key on the two fields which you want to be unique together.

Answer (score 0):

Use a composite unique index

```
ALTER TABLE Teach ADD UNIQUE INDEX([exam class], [exam time]);
```

Here's some additional information on composite unique indices if you would like

http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLUnique.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Unique constraint is what you are looking for.
Define unique constraint for columns `exam time` and `exam class`.

[Documentation for MS SQL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)